# Regular expression to extrat date from columns in a dataframe

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have to deal with a dataframe whose structure looks like below:

```
print (df)
        2012-02-23~2012-02-29  2012-03-01~2012-03-08
Team A                    213                   3213
Team B                    321                   3213
```

I am trying to modify the column name to extract the date part after charcter ~.

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract(r'~(.*)')
df
```

I am using the code above, however the result I get looks like below:

```
print (df)
        (2012-02-29,)  (2012-03-08,)
Team A            213           3213
Team B            321           3213
```

The issue is where is the comman comes from? and why there is () in every column, my goal is the get the table looks like below and covert the datetype to datestamp.

```
        2012-02-29  2012-03-08
Team A         213        3213
Team B         321        3213
```

Comment: Just something I noticed but if you want to extract dates (as per your question) do note that 2012-02-35 is not a valid date. Is this a typo? Or are you dealing with faulty data?

Comment: @JvdV - I guess, so in text version I change it to `2012-02-29`

Comment: @JvdV it is text, how to change it to datetime?

Comment: First, let us know if it's a typo or if you are dealing with faulty data showing dates that are not valid? And in case if it's not a valid date, what is it supposed to be? e.g `2012-2-29` or `2012-3-6` or so.. Or is the change made by @jezrael correct?

Comment: i think pd.to_datetime is enough here, i just need to pass the format paramater in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `expand=False` should help here for avoid `MultiIndex` converted to tuples:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract(r'~(.*)', expand=False)
print (df)
        2012-02-29  2012-03-08
Team A         213        3213
Team B         321        3213
```

Or use `split` with select second values of lists:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('~').str[1]
print (df)
        2012-02-29  2012-03-08
Team A         213        3213
Team B         321        3213
```

Comment: thanks so much, this is helpfule, one more quesiton, curretnly the rsult is string, so how can change to column to datetime datatype?

Comment: @Rowling - Then use `df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns.str.extract(r'~(.*)', expand=False))`